# Is there a limit to how much stuff you can carry?

Tags: star-wars-age-of-rebellion, encumbrance

I have just purchased and run through the beginning mission of the Age of Rebellion. During the game a question came up that I couldn't answer:

How much stuff can you carry in your inventory? Is there a limit?

This may be a rule that is in the core rule book but I only have a beginner rule book. (If there is a rule in the core book please to tell me that it's there and I'll go buy it, haha.)

Comment: Potential answerers, please make sure to not answer questions like this by just pasting in the full rules from the corebook.  See [Can non-open-license rules be discussed, or not?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/6044) for why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each item in the core books has a listed **encumbrance** value. A character can carry **5 plus his brawn score** worth of items. An item emcumbrance value does not equal weight per se, but how much effort you have to make to carry it around without trouble.

And by trouble i mean one setback (black) on all checks related to agility or brawn. If you go above twice that threshold, you lose your free maneuver you get each round (unless he uses two strain per maneuver, as normal).

Certain items, like a belt with pockets, will increase that limit by one, while certain backpacks will increase it by another point or two, depending on the quality of the backpack.

Those rules are explained on all three core books, pick one of them and you are good to go. *Note that the beginner box does not have rules for encumbrance*.

Comment: Legend thanks ill pick up the core book next time im at the shops cheers.